# Determine number of entrants and exits in each year in panel data

Tags: pandas, multi-index, panel-data

I have three data frames with the same variables for the same firms but corresponding to different years (2016, 2017, 2018). The ID variable corresponds to a firm ID.

```
df2016 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [99,101,102,103,104], "A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B": [2,4,6,8,10], "year": [2016,2016,2016,2016,2016]})
    ID  A   B   year
0   99  1   2   2016
1   101 2   4   2016
2   102 3   6   2016
3   103 4   8   2016
4   104 5   10  2016

df2017 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [100,101,102,104], "A": [5,6,7,8], "B": [9,11,13,15], "year": [2017,2017,2017,2017]})

    ID  A   B   year
0   100 5   9   2017
1   101 6   11  2017
2   102 7   13  2017
3   104 8   15  2017

df2018 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [100,106], "A": [6,8], "B": [13,15], "year": [2018,2018]})
    ID  A   B   year
0   100 6   13  2018
1   106 8   15  2018
```

### Goal

I want to determine the number of entering firms and exiting firms in each year.

Specifically, I would like:

1. A new variable called `entry` that equals 1 if the firm ID was not in the data last year and is the data this year; and zero otherwise.
2. Another variable called `exit` that equals 1 if the firm ID is in the data this year but is not in the data next year; and zero otherwise.
3. Edge cases of entering in the first year or exiting in the last year could be handled however is best.

### Desired Output (something like this):

```
            A   B    enter  exit
ID  year                
99  2016    1.0 2.0     1   1
101 2016    2.0 4.0     1   0
102 2016    3.0 6.0     1   0
103 2016    4.0 8.0     1   1
104 2016    5.0 10.0    1   0
100 2017    5.0 9.0     1   0
101 2017    6.0 11.0    0   1
102 2017    7.0 13.0    0   1
104 2017    8.0 15.0    0   1
100 2018    6.0 13.0    0   0
106 2018    8.0 15.0    1   0
```

I start by concatenating the three years of data and setting the multi-index to (ID, year):

```
df = pd.concat([df2016, df2017, df2018])

df.set_index(["ID", "year"], inplace=True)
           A    B
ID  year        
99  2016    1   2
101 2016    2   4
102 2016    3   6
103 2016    4   8
104 2016    5   10
100 2017    5   9
101 2017    6   11
102 2017    7   13
104 2017    8   15
100 2018    6   13
106 2018    8   15
```

Not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.concat([df2016, df2017, df2018], ignore_index=True)
g = df.groupby('ID')['year']
df['entry'] = g.diff(1).ne(1).astype(int)
df['exit'] = g.diff(-1).ne(-1).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
     ID  A   B  year  entry  exit
0    99  1   2  2016      1     1
1   101  2   4  2016      1     0
2   102  3   6  2016      1     0
3   103  4   8  2016      1     1
4   104  5  10  2016      1     0
5   100  5   9  2017      1     0
6   101  6  11  2017      0     1
7   102  7  13  2017      0     1
8   104  8  15  2017      0     1
9   100  6  13  2018      0     1
10  106  8  15  2018      1     1
```

Comment: Note that you need to ensure ascending sorting of the years for the logic to work ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the shifted years, if the value is found then we have a 0, then fill the NaNs with 1:

```
dfs = [df2016, df2017, df2018]
df = pd.concat(dfs)

cols = ['ID', 'year']
df = (df
 .merge(df[cols].assign(year=df['year'].add(1), enter=0), on=cols, how='left')
 .merge(df[cols].assign(year=df['year'].sub(1), exit=0), on=cols, how='left')
 .fillna({'enter': 1, 'exit': 1}, downcast='infer')
)
```

output:

```
     ID  A   B  year  enter  exit
0    99  1   2  2016      1     1
1   101  2   4  2016      1     0
2   102  3   6  2016      1     0
3   103  4   8  2016      1     1
4   104  5  10  2016      1     0
5   100  5   9  2017      1     0
6   101  6  11  2017      0     1
7   102  7  13  2017      0     1
8   104  8  15  2017      0     1
9   100  6  13  2018      0     1
10  106  8  15  2018      1     1
```

Comment: Ok thanks but is there a way to do this using multi-index? I gather in order to do a lot panel data stuff, it is important to multi-index your data by the ID and the time. If my task cannot easily be done with the data multi-indexed in that way, how would I transform the index from multi-index to regular index in order to carry out out your solution? So assume I am starting with the df generated by taking your df and doing `df = df.set_index(["ID", "year"])`. Then how do I get it back to the non-multi indexed state?

I'm pretty sure a panel data software like R or Stata would use multiindex.

Comment: You should be able to use a MultiIndex and `join`? Can you give it a try (or provide a constructor for the multiindexed df, I'm on my phone it's to much of a pain to generate it)

Comment: Here's code that will allow to you construct the multi-indexed df

```
df2016 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [99,101,102,103,104], "A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B": [2,4,6,8,10], "year": [2016,2016,2016,2016,2016]})

df2017 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [100,101,102,104], "A": [5,6,7,8], "B": [9,11,13,15], "year": [2017,2017,2017,2017]})

df2018 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [100,106], "A": [6,8], "B": [13,15], "year": [2018,2018]})

df = pd.concat([df2016, df2017, df2018])

df.set_index(["ID", "year"], inplace=True)

```


Also [linked](https://dpaste.org/Rezqe) here if its easier to read.

Comment: @Smithey It's possible to use the index but a bit convoluted if you do not want to copy the data. The easiest is indeed to temporarily reset the index as columns then set it back as MultiIndex

Comment: Ok, but btw I just tried your answer and it gives `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_dtypes'`
It's a few layers of complexity beyond where I'm at atm. I do understand the other answer though, so that's ok.

Comment: The `convert_dtypes()` is not strictly needed (this is to convert to integers), you can remove it (you probably have an older pandas version, which one?). Can you test the update?